# Select complete matching between two table

Tags: sql

I have two tables

t1

```
col1    col2
A        1
A        2 
B        1
C        2
```

t2

```
col1
1
2
```

I want to retrieve the records in tab1 which match all the records in tab2,

For the given scenario, I want to output A  only because it has both 1 and 2 in col2 where as B and C has only a 1 or a 2 (not both).

Comment: What DBM program are you using? MSSQL? MySQL? The program will have a bearing on the syntax of this query, and also what functions we can use to help you...

Comment: How many different values in your `t1.col2` can there be?  And, what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can write the query this way:

```
select t1.col1
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.col2 = t2.col1
group by t1.col1
having count(distinct t1.col2) = (select count(distinct t2.col1) from t2);
```

This counts the number of matching values in the first table and compares it to the total number of values in the table.